# Javascript looping through inputs and grabbing data

Tags: javascript, for-loop, input

I have a page that will create new input text fields if needed by pushing a button. The code creates the input with a unique id based on a number plus text. My issue is grabbing said text out of the text field. There is a hard coded input that has the number 0 in its name. so enumAmount++ starts at 0 and is increased before adding in a new row on the page.

This is how I create my new input text field.

```
$('#add-check-checkbox').click(function(){
            enumAmount++;
            $('.checkbox-table').append('<tbody id="checkbox"><tr><td width="50px" align="center"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggler"><i id=' + enumAmount + "-status" + ' class="fa fa-lg fa-toggle-on green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td><td><input id=' + enumAmount + "-check-enum-name"+' type="text" /></td><td><input id=' + enumAmount + "-check-enum-lib-id" + 'type="text" /></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i id="" & enumAmount & "-check-delete" class="fa fa-lg fa-trash-o red" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>');
        });
```

That works exactly how I want it to. It will increase the enumAmount and input the number in the id field to create a custom id for the input field.

My issue is my javascript for loop. It won't replace i for a number and I don't get any data. ( for loop is updated based on comments)

```
var enumers = {};
for (var i = 0; i < enumAmount; i++){
     var key = $("input#check-enum-name-" + i).val();
     if (key) {
          alert(key) // shows the text i had in the check-enum-name input
          enumers[key] = $("input#check-enum-lib-id-" + i).val();
     }
}
```

What have I wrong with my for loop?

Comment: Use a `var` in front of `i` in your loop. Also `enumers` is an object not an array and objects don't have a `push` method, only arrays do.

Comment: `var enumers = {};` should be `var enumers = [];`, like GillesC said

Comment: When I do an alert(enumers["testEnum"]) it returns undefined. When I post  it to the back end via ajax for me to process in django/python when I print it out it returns as None. Is there something I'm still missing?

Comment: if it is an array you have to access it by the index. enumers["testEnum"] will definitely return undefined. if you are looking for a key value pair. create an object instead.

Comment: const enumers = {}; for (var i=0; i< enumAmount; i++){ ... enumers[key] = value }. Where key is $("input#"+ i +"-check-enum-name").val() and value is  $("input#"+ i +"-check-enum-lib-id").val()

Comment: what is the initial value of `enumAmount`? Even if you have initialized it to zero, you are incrementing it before creating your input element. So, the first input element will have `enumAmount` = 1. However, you are starting your for loop from 0

Comment: BTW, what is the output that you are getting? Any errors? anything?

Comment: @sid-m there is a default input that starts at 0, then when you add a new one it goes to 1.

Comment: @sid-m the output in the alert just says undefined. Even with changing it to how Alan suggested how to do it. With google chrome developer debugger there are no errors that are out putted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

1. Per [HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), a valid [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute does not begin with a number. Though if you just want to use HTML 5 standards, then that is okay.

> **Note**: Using characters except ASCII letters and digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)</sup>

Move the integer to the end of the id attributes - e.g.:
    `id="check-enum-name-" + i`

2. Use the var keyword to create the variable *i* in the for loop
   `for (var i=0; i< enumAmount; i++){`
3. An object has no function *push()*- though [array does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). When setting properties on *enumers*, use bracket syntax with the key:
   `var key = $("input#check-enum-name-" + i ).val();
    enumers[key] = $("input#check-enum-lib-id-" + i).val();`
4. Wait to increment the value of *enumAmount* until after adding the new row:

   `$('.checkbox-table').append('<tr ...</tr>');
   enumAmount++;`
5. While it is okay to add a new [*tbody*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) tag with each row, it is not necessary. The tbody tag in your append code has a distinct id value (i.e. *checkbox*) so with multiple *tbody* tags those values are not unique.

> The TBODY start tag is always required except when the table contains only one table body and no table head or foot sections. The TBODY end tag may always be safely omitted.<sup>[2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY)</sup>

```js
var enumAmount = 0;
$('#add-check-checkbox').click(function() {
  $('.checkbox-table').append('<tr><td width="50px" align="center"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggler"><i id="status-' + enumAmount + '" class="fa fa-lg fa-toggle-on green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td><td><input id="check-enum-name-' + enumAmount + '" +  type="text" /></td><td><input id="check-enum-lib-id-' + enumAmount + '" type="text" /></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i id="check-delete-' + enumAmount + '" class="fa fa-lg fa-trash-o red" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
  enumAmount++;
});
$('#serialize').click(function() {
  var enumers = {};
  var status;
  for (var i = 0; i < enumAmount; i++) {
    var key = $("input#check-enum-name-" + i).val();
    if (key) { //ensure value was entered for key
      enumers[key] = $("input#check-enum-lib-id-" + i).val();
    }
  }
  console.log('enumers: ', enumers);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-check-checkbox">Add</button>&nbsp;
<button id="serialize">Seralize</button>
<form>
  <table class="checkbox-table">
    
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I updated it to be like yours. my alert(key) pushes out the correct key but when i do the console.log nothing is returned. it just says enumers: and then doesn't list anything. (I'm updating the for statement in the first post as well)